# "Wait For File" operation in PDI does not recognize windows network drives

Tags: pentaho

In PDI 4.5 the "Wait for File" operation in a job does not seem to recognize windows network drives, i.e.  using a path like Z:\stuff\watch\test.txt where Z: is network drive and not on the local machine.

Has anybody had this problem?  Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full windows path rather than the mapped drive, i.e.:

\servername\sharename\stuff\watch\test.txt